# FileNotFound exception when sending file with httpurlconnection

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I need to send a request containing both data and a file to a server. When I just try to send the data it works, but if I also include the code for the file I get a FileNotFoundException, even though I can clearly see the number of bytes read from the file.

I have tried to set a bigger connection timeout, but nothing seems to be working.

This is the function which is supposed to send the data:

```
public String multipartRequest(String urlTo, Map<String, String> parmas, String filepath, String filefield) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";

        String result = "";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        String[] q = filepath.split("/");
        int idx = q.length - 1;
        Log.e("ceva", q[idx]);

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlTo);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            if (!filepath.equals(""))
            {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>22){
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    requestPermissions(permissions,1);
                }
                File file = new File(filepath);
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
                String fileMimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);

                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + fileMimeType + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Log.e("baiti", Integer.toString(bytesRead));
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                //fileInputStream.close();
            }


            // Upload POST Data
            Iterator<String> keys = parmas.keySet().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = parmas.get(key);

                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(value);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            Log.e("something", "At least I got here");

            if (200 != connection.getResponseCode()) {
                //throw new Exception("Failed to upload code:" + connection.getInputStream() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage() + " "  + connection.getContent());
            }

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("cam asta e", e.toString());
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            return this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        }

    }
```

I expect to get a 200 code and a json as an answer, but instead I get 422 and the FileNotFoundException, even though the "At least I got here" line seems to be executed wherever I place it, so the code doesn't immediately get to the catch block.

Comment: could you try flushing outputstream before checking for response code?

Comment: @JVOneLife Same thing, I still get the ```java.io.FileNotFoundException```.

Comment: why dont you simply use something like `okhttp` / `volley` etc?

Comment: This is equivalent to HTTP 404. Your copy loop is wrong and your use of `available()` is invalid: see the Javadoc.

Comment: You are requesting for permission and still reading from file?

Comment: @user207421 Could you please tell me how to use it correctly?

Comment: @UmaSankar Yes, I'm reading from file afterwards.

Comment: But your code does not look like!! You might be missing `return` statement after request for permission. Can you post stack trace?

Comment: so why dont you use something like [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-file) or [this](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/11/21/upload-file-okhttp/)?

Comment: @pskink Thanks, it worked with okhttp!

Comment: good, code is much shorter now, isnt it?